# How to block all users from a site in case of emergency?

Tags: php, mysql, security

I'm developing a game in PHP+Mysql that is hosted in a shared web hosting.

I'm very concerned of the security, because in games is very common that some people try to cheat or broke the game.

Until now, I have tested XSS, SQL injection, check permissions of folders, secure passwords, ... but well, I know my limitations and I want to be prepared in case something unexpected happens (I don't know, maybe some techique that I don't know, or a check that I miss, a guessed password ...)

If I realize of some of this, my first action I think that should be block the access to all users, isolate the site and then check and repair the bug. (It's only a free game, I think I can afford this downtime). How can I do this?

Comment: This is really a server configuration question. Belongs on Server Fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make .htaccess file in the root of webserver with contents:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.1.1 -- here is your IP
```

It will block all requests except from mentioned IP

Comment: A better solution is to specify an auto-prepend in the webserver config - this allows you to be selective / responsive e.g. restricting access to non-static content, redirecting to a static sorry page for blocked stuff...

Answer (score 0):

Stop the web server. Configure it to listen on `127.0.0.1` only (it usually listens on `0.0.0.0` which means that is accepts connections from everybody) and start it. This way the game will be accessible only from the host of the web server.

Comment: The problem is that is a tipical shared web hosting. I can't stop it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say have a `.htaccess` file ready, but not in place which, if you put into your web directory it redirects all requests to something like `mydomain.com/downformaintenance.php`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to tell your webserver to no longer deliver anything for this site.  Using Apache you could achieve this by a .htaccess file:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```

The second way would be to implement it into your website. E.g. in your dispatching script you first check for the existance of a file and then simply exit:

```
if(file_exists(__DIR__ . '/close_it')) {
  exit;
}
```

HTH